# How to traverse WPF layout parents across template boundary?

Tags: wpf

I want to find an element further up in the WPF layout, but if I use the `FrameworkElement.Parent` property, it will return `null` at the template boundary if the initial element is declared in a template.

Comment: I couldn't find this problem online and found the solution by chance, so I'm putting this here in the hopes it may help someone who has the name problem. `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(reference)` seems to behave like the `Parent` property, but I didn't check thoroughly enough to add it to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(reference)` returns parents in the final WPF layout even across template boundaries.